# don't include all aws-sdk for node lambdas

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a bunch of aws lambdas written in node 12.   I've discovered that require("aws-sdk") takes ages - like 3 seconds all by itself.   I also discovered that if I just want to hit dynamo, I can just load a tiny little bit of it, by going:

```js
    const DynamoDB = require('aws-sdk/clients/dynamodb')
```

which ends up being *heaps* faster.   However, I now need to call a lambda - ie I'm doing

```js
    const aws = require('aws-sdk');
    const lambda = new aws.Lambda( );
```

but I couldn't find any way of requiring *just* lambda - eg I'd like something like this to work:

```js
    const Lambda = require("aws-sdk/Lambda");
    const lambda = new Lambda();
```

but it doesn't.    Is there any way of just including lambda functionality, without the whole aws sdk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so - turns out the solution was quite simple - Andre's answer made me look a lot closer and I came up with this:

```js
  const Lambda = require("aws-sdk/clients/lambda");
```

Answer (score 2):

You should check the [JS AWS SDK v3](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3), quoting from their repo:

> The *AWS SDK for JavaScript v3 gamma* is a rewrite of V2 with some great new features. As with version 2, it enables you to easily work with Amazon Web Services, but has been written in TypeScript and adds several frequently requested features, like modularized packages.

With it you can do things like:

```js
const { Lambda } = require("@aws-sdk/client-lambda");
```

As the version suggests, it's still a pre-release so depending on your requirements and use case you might want to hold off until it's more stable.

Comment: thanks - I'll give it a go - this is for a new thing that's entirely my own - so bleeding edge is fine :).

Comment: so - couldn't get it working because for various reasons I'm not uploading any code - I'm just on amazon - and referencing an external lib seemed to much work - however - you made me think about it - and I found a solution - so thx.